# Delete a range in MS WORD

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, docx

### Need to Accomplish

I want to clean up the formatting for a Word document I have. I want everything between `<` and `>` to be deleted.

### I Tried

I've tried using is MS Word's **"Find and Replace**" feature by using
 `[\<(*{1,})\>]` in the "**Find what**" box and left the **replace** box empty. When do this, it doesn't delete everything within that range (between the `<` and `>`). However, it deletes both `<` and `>` symbols as well as every period `.` in my document.

### Example

If the document has `< blah, blah>` I want everything in `< blah, blah>` these symbols `< blah, blah>` to be deleted but I want to keep the `<` and `>` symbols. I just need everything between the symbols to be deleted.

Comment: Please clarify your "current" example formatted data and your "expected" example formatted data. What you have, what you need, and what you have tried just needs to be [edit]ed and written a little more clearly I think. Give it a shot with an [edit] when you get a chance to draw more accurate answers.

Comment: was that a bit clearer?

Comment: I edited your question for you and I'm talking about clarifying what exactly you are trying to accomplish. I think my [edit] is what you are requesting but look it over and you can see how I cleaned it up a bit but understanding your ultimate goal is what needs to be clarified I think if what I edited is not that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to select content between two characters as you describe in your question, but there is a way to select content between pages.

1. Identify the page number where the content you wish to select  begins and ends.
2. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>, then enter the start page number.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
5. Press <kbd>F8</kbd>
6. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> again, and enter the end page number.
7. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I hope this helps or is at least close to what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In "find what" try:

```
\<*\>
```

and in replace:

```
< >
```

and use regex search. Note, that this won't work if there are no characters between < and > symbols.